# Mysql deadlock on non unique index

Tags: innodb, mysql-8.0, deadlock

I'm getting the deadlock on MySQL v8.0.32 which is very strange for me because of the following:

1. I'm trying to insert the data: parent-child record (users, user_roles) - each transactions inserts new user and record in join table with some role.
2. The index that is causing deadlock (on user_roles) is not unique and I see that `gap` lock is not used.
3. Sequence of statements is the same and not like in classical deadlock example (when `T1` changes `table A`, then `B` and `T2` vice versa - `table B` than `table A`)

```
CREATE TABLE `user_roles` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `context_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `context_id` int NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_rails_dcd6720bf9` (`created_by`),
  KEY `index_user_roles_on_deleted_at` (`deleted_at`),
  KEY `index_user_roles_on_role_id` (`role_id`),
  KEY `fk_rails_3c5703b833` (`updated_by`),
  KEY `index_user_roles_on_user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_318345354e` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_3369e0d5fc` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_3c5703b833` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_dcd6720bf9` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=450 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The code that is executed concurrently is the following (simplified):

```
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO users ...;
DELETE FROM user_roles WHERE `user_roles`.`user_id` = 'id of inserted user' AND `user_roles`.`context_type` = 'Trial' AND `user_roles`.`context_id` = 'some constant id'
INSERT INTO user_roles (`role_id`, `user_id`, `context_type`, `context_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (...)


COMMIT;
```

Deadlock information:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2023-10-10 16:49:52 0x70000ed4b000
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 23884460, ACTIVE 1 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 10 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 1862, OS thread handle 123145570869248, query id 1067189 localhost 127.0.0.1 root update
INSERT INTO `user_roles` (`role_id`, `user_id`, `context_type`, `context_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (85, 397, 'Trial', 6, '2023-10-10 13:49:52', '2023-10-10 13:49:52')

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 841074 page no 9 n bits 496 index index_user_roles_on_user_id of table `tap-prototype-copy`.`user_roles` trx id 23884460 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 841074 page no 9 n bits 496 index index_user_roles_on_user_id of table `tap-prototype-copy`.`user_roles` trx id 23884460 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 23884464, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 10 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 1864, OS thread handle 123145565544448, query id 1067336 localhost 127.0.0.1 root update
INSERT INTO `user_roles` (`role_id`, `user_id`, `context_type`, `context_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (85, 398, 'Trial', 6, '2023-10-10 13:49:52', '2023-10-10 13:49:52')

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 841074 page no 9 n bits 496 index index_user_roles_on_user_id of table `tap-prototype-copy`.`user_roles` trx id 23884464 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 841074 page no 9 n bits 496 index index_user_roles_on_user_id of table `tap-prototype-copy`.`user_roles` trx id 23884464 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

As we can see we're inserting data for different users (397, 398) and gap locking is not used. So what is the reason for the deadlock then? Seems like a very common and simple situation, but I can't understand what can we improve here.

Thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE**: in respond to Rick James:

1. By joint (join) tables I mean `user_roles` table as it `join` (many-to many) `users` and `roles`.
2. Yeah it was a simplistic description, I omitted the following detail. So no `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`, but I have in between DELETE, eg:

```
DELETE FROM `user_roles` WHERE `user_roles`.`user_id` = 398 AND `user_roles`.`context_type` = 'Trial' AND `user_roles`.`context_id` = 64
```

I also updated pseudo code above. When I remove this DELETE - deadlock goes away. Looks like a root of the problem, but for some reason it is not mentioned in deadlock report.

`Were you inserting user rows and getting back 397 and 398 for user_id?` - yes, insert into `users` is the first statement.

3. I can't get rid of `id` in favor of composite primary key - and it doesn't look like it can help here...

---

**UPDATE (2023-10-17)**

I was able to explore locks that these statements produce and discovered that `supremum pseudo-record` lock is utilized. This is what I've found in [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html):

> The supremum is not a real index record, so, in effect, this next-key lock locks only the gap following the largest index value

Strange that gap locks are not mentioned in deadlock report, but this explanation looks like an explanation here: because we are adding new `user` record and insert data into related join table `user_roles`. This involves incrementing user ID - as well as largest index value in `user_roles`. This is how I treat the docs. If this is the case, then I'm frustrated by the fact that we can't workaround the deadlocks in such very simple situation...

```
mysql> select * from performance_schema.data_locks \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140575951646488:851842:140575916454504
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 24023562
            THREAD_ID: 4671
             EVENT_ID: 11
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: tap-test
          OBJECT_NAME: user_roles
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: NULL
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140575916454504
            LOCK_TYPE: TABLE
            LOCK_MODE: IX
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140575951646488:851850:140575916454416
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 24023562
            THREAD_ID: 4671
             EVENT_ID: 9
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: tap-test
          OBJECT_NAME: users
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: NULL
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140575916454416
            LOCK_TYPE: TABLE
            LOCK_MODE: IX
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140575951646488:850032:9:1:140576159006240
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 24023562
            THREAD_ID: 4671
             EVENT_ID: 11
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: tap-test
          OBJECT_NAME: user_roles
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: index_user_roles_on_user_id
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140576159006240
            LOCK_TYPE: RECORD
            LOCK_MODE: X
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: supremum pseudo-record
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "and joint tables"?  Sounds like we need more details.

Comment: Are there any `SELECTs` in the transaction?  Do they have `FOR UPDATE` on them?  Were you inserting user rows and getting back 397 and 398 for urser_id?

Comment: Is the combo `(user_id, role_id)` unique?  If so, do you think it reasonable to get rid of `id` and make that pair the `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: @RickJames, thanks for the response! I answered your questions in the question body

Comment: How did you get the new `user_id` after the initial `INSERT INTO users`?  I assume it was something like '`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`;?

Comment: Yes LAST_INSERT_ID is used

Comment: Good.  That part is optimal.

Comment: @RickJames I updated the post with new information, can you have a look please?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE user_roles
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    DROP COLUMN id,
    DROP INDEX index_user_roles_on_role_id,
    DROP INDEX index_user_roles_on_user_id,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY(user_id, role_id),
    ADD INDEX(role_id, user_id),
    ADD INDEX(context_id, context_type, user_id) ;
```

Benefits:

- The last index will at least make the `DELETE` faster, and possibly lock fewer rows.

  Alas, I don't think that "LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK" gives any clues about the locks caused by the `DELETE`.
- Since this is a many-to-many table, `id` is a waste of performance; most of the suggestions are for replacing it with better indexes.  (See also [*Many-to-many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) )

  I assume no other table references `user_roles.id`?

Comment: unfortunately, we can't transform separate indexes `index_user_roles_on_role_id`/`index_user_roles_on_user_id` into composite, because they correspond to foreign keys and we want to have fast search by these keys. While query by `user_id` won't use index on (role_id, user_id).

Comment: also I didn't still understand why `DELETE from user_roles for user_id = X` blocks `INSERT into user_roles for user_id = Y`. Your suggestions do not answer this question. (I'm still trying to understand how we read ID of inserted record, because it is done under the hood by ORM)

Comment: @AndreyKhataev - Drop those indexes and at the same time you build the new indexes; the FK definition should realize that the new keys are sufficient.  Also, the Optimizer failed to use the longer index when the shorter one is there: `INDEX(a), INDEX(a,b)`.  If there is further trouble, `DISABLE` the FKs while changing the indexes, then re-enable.

Comment: I don't know whether the `DELETE` interferes; I was running out of ideas.  Improving the index will at least help its speed.

Comment: @AndreyKhataev - If you are unwilling to change the PK, try adding `ADD INDEX(context_id, context_type, user_id)`.

Comment: Is the intent to replace the row(s) with 'id of inserted user', 'Trial', 'some constant id'?  If so, use an `UPDATE` instead of `DELETE` + `INSERT`.

Comment: Do you mean to add index on `(context_id, context_type, user_id)` instead of `user_id` ? If yes - it won't be used if we query just by `user_id` ...

Comment: Regarding UPDATE instead of DELETE+INSERT. Interesting idea, but since there could be the case when record does not exist, we need to use `UPSERT`. I need to figure out if this is possible in mysql. Still this looks like a workaround for database bug ))

Comment: @AndreyKhataev - See `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` -- This does either an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, as needed.  (Also called "upsert".)

Comment: Yes, add that 3-column Index.